# Multiple condition operators in Where-Object

Tags: powershell, csv

```
#foo.csv
Month, Name, First, Second, Third, Status
2015/01, 'Google', 02-02-2014, 03-02-2014, 03-02-2015, "Lost"
2015/01, 'Google', 03-01-2014,  03-01-2014, 03-02-2015, "Active"
2015/02, 'Google', 06-02-2013,  03-01-2014, N/A, "Lost"
2015/02, 'Yahoo', 07-02-2013,  06-01-2015, 03-02-2015, "Active"
2015/02, 'Google', 07-02-2013,  06-01-2015, 03-02-2015, "Lost" 
2015/02, 'Yahoo', 03-01-2014,  06-01-2015, N/A, "Active"
2015/02, 'Google', 06-01-2015,  06-01-2015, 03-02-2015, "Lost" 
2014/12, 'Yahoo', 03-01-2014,  06-01-2015, 03-02-2014, "Active"
2014/12, 'Google', 03-05-2014,  06-01-2015, N/A, "Active" 
2014/12, 'Yahoo', 06-01-2015,  06-01-2015, 03-02-2014, "Active"

Import-Csv "E:\foo.csv"  |
Where-Object {($_."Name" -eq "Google") `
-and ($_."Third" -gt (get-date).AddDays(-27).ToString("yyy-MM-dd") -or $_."C3 Date" -eq "N/A") `
-and # where month is last two months while Status is only Active ` 
-and # no current months (Feb) data/values of last years from First and Second column }
```

Note:
Month column values are in string format. (So no problem there). Rest are in date format of dd-mm-yyyy (e.g 23-12-2014 )

I am trying to select only desired records from above csv file, the selection steps are as follows :

1. First select only Google records.
2. Then select only those records where Third column date is of current
   month or N/A.
3. Then take only those records where Month value equals last two month
   and at the same time status should be Active.
4. And at last, skip those records for current months (Feb) values from
   past year (e.g 2014 /02, 2013/02, but not 2015 /02) from First and
   Second column.

I am able to write script till, 2 step only. And output is matching desired count.
3 and 4 steps contains multiple if conditions/logic, which I am not able to write and understand.

**Note:** 2nd and 9th records in foo.csv are the exact records we are looking for, who satisfies all conditions.

**Edit:**
9 th record corrected.
When I tried Matt's code, I received following error:

```
The operation '[System.Int32] - [System.DateTime]' is not defined.
At line:8 char:29
```

In my culture info I can see en-GB, but I want it to be independent of culture. Previously it was logic part, with which I was struggling, but now its date (formatting and matching) issue.
I was reading about date and time formatting for past 2 days. I tried changing yyyy to yy or yyy, even that produced error. Still trying to get it right for just 2 nd condition regarding date issue, but no luck yet.

**Edit 2:**
Below is POC code, which does few parts, but I can't control date format here, because in future data may change in csv dd-mm-yyyy to mm-dd-yy or something else.

```
Import-Csv E:\foo.csv | 
Select-Object @{Label="Third"; Expression={[datetime]$_.Third}} |
Where-Object { $_.Third -gt [datetime]'01-03-2015' } |
Format-Table -Auto
```

Also, is there any chance that while converting date to datetime format, N/A would remain as it is?

Comment: _but I can't control date format here, because in future data may change in csv dd-mm-yyyy to mm-dd-yy or something else._ If you cant guarentee the date format then it makes date calculations _almost_ impossible. If that is the case we cannot use `ParseExact` but possibly `Parse` might be able to figure it out.

Comment: Please note that it is now March and your expectations for data return have changed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*So* many condition to test for that are not present in your sample data but this can be done in one where clause which is not more difficult to read or understand that multiple where clauses.

I also agree with beatcracker in that your expected results are incorrect as the 9th record is not "Active"

```powershell
$culture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
$today = Get-Date "02-27-2015"
Import-CSV c:\temp\foo.csv | Select-Object @{Label="Month";Expression={[datetime]$_.Month}},
        Name, @{Label="First";Expression={[datetime]::ParseExact($_.First,"dd-MM-yyyy",$culture)}},
        @{Label="Second";Expression={[datetime]::ParseExact($_.Second,"dd-MM-yyyy",$culture)}},
        @{Label="Third";Expression={[datetime]::ParseExact($_.Third,"dd-MM-yyyy",$culture)}},
        Status | 
    Where-Object {
        ($_.Name -eq "'Google'") -and      # Condition 1
        (!$_.Third -or (($_.Third).Month -eq $today.Month)) -and # Condition 2
        (($today.Month - $_.Month + (($today.Year - $_.Year) * 12)) -lt 3) -and # Condition 3.1
        ($_.Status -eq "Active") -and # Condition 3.2
        (!((($_.First).Month -eq $today.Month) -and (($_.First).Year -ne $today.Year))) -and # Condition 4.1
        (!((($_.Second).Month -eq $today.Month) -and (($_.Second).Year -ne $today.Year))) # Condition 4.2
    } | Select-Object @{L="Month";E={($_.Month).ToString("yyyy/MM")}},Name,
            @{L="First";E={($_.First).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")}},
            @{L="Second";E={($_.Second).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")}},
            @{L="Last";E={If($_.Third){($_.Third).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")}Else{"N/A"}}},Status |
    Export-CSV "c:\temp\outputfile.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

One of the larger issues you were running into is that you were doing date arithmetic on string and not date objects. When data is imported with `Import-CSV` is it cast as a string. To address that we run a `Select` and use calculated expressions to cast the data into `[datetime]` objects.

To help understand the `Where` clauses I have comments at the end so you know which clause was meant to address which conditions of yours. A couple I broke up into more clauses to help with readability.

One issue also is that I dont know what your data time format is for First,Second and Third. I assumed it was "dd-MM-yyyy" based on your assumptions. Let me know if there are issues here

Depending on your output needs you would need to format your string to match what you want. Waiting to see if we are on the right track or not.

**Update from comments**

To get the results you expect I changed the `Get-Date`s to a variable `$today`. For the purpose of testing I set `$today` to February 27. Simply change to `$today = Get-Date` for production data. I also updated the logic for the the 4th condition. Let me know if this works now.

Also added another `Select` clause at the end that will configure the output to be the exact as the input. You will see if the Third column is null that "N/A" is put back in the file.

Also I did not get your error with your test code. Let me know if you have more issues.

**Credit where credit is due**

The calculation for how to determine the month difference comes from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21053007/3829407

Comment: Hi, you were right, about date time format. I really can't understand, it. More I try more confusing it becomes, with new things like culture, exceptions, powershell version, formats. etc. Kindly see edit for more info.

Comment: Thanks, for your information and explanations, now I feel little more confident while dealing with csv files using PowerShell. Did some practice test with actual data and it is giving desired output.

Answer (score 2):

You'd better split all those steps to the separate `Where-Object`'s, because otherwise it will be fiendishly hard to construct and debug such statement. And this is what I did. The problem is, that while you say that records **#2** and **#9** are the records you're looking for, the record **#9** fails your rule **#3**:

> Then take only those records where `Month` value equals last two month
>   and at the same time status should be `Active`.

The record is:

> 2014/12, 'Google', 03-05-2014,  06-01-2015, N/A, "Lost"

and it has `Status` set to `Lost`. So it's only the record **#2** that will be shown by the code below:

**EDIT:** Here is very verbose script, that will process your CSV's. Save it as `ProcessCSV.ps1` and run like this: `.\ProcessCSV -Path 'E:\foo.csv' -Verbose`. It should display *a lot* of debug data, that will help to diagnose what's going wrong. Example:

```
VERBOSE: Importing CSV's
VERBOSE: ==============================[ Processing record #1 ]==============================
VERBOSE: [Selecting only Google records]
VERBOSE: Name: Google
VERBOSE: Found Google record, returning: True
VERBOSE: [Selecting only those records where Third column date is of current month (3) in this year (2015) or N/A]
VERBOSE: Third column value is: 03/03/2015 00:00:00
VERBOSE: Third column value converted to date is: 3 марта 2015 г.
VERBOSE: Third column date is in current year (2015): 2015
VERBOSE: Third column date is in current month (3): 3, returning: True
VERBOSE: [Selecting records where Month value equals last two months and Status is Active]
VERBOSE: Status column value is: Lost
VERBOSE: Status column value is not equal to: Active, returning False
```

Script forces custom date formatting for every column and you can modify it yourself in the future. Look for the `$DateFmt` variable in the `Begin` block of `Select-Data` function:

```
$DateFmt = @{
    # The year as a four-digit number
    # The month, from 01 through 12
    Month = 'yyyy/MM'
...
```

Kudos to **Matt** for `Select-Object` with custom `[DateTime]` idea, works much better that way!

`ProcessCSV.ps1` script:

```powershell
[CmdLetBinding()]
Param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [ValidateScript({
        if(!(Test-Path -LiteralPath $_ -PathType Leaf))
        {
            throw "File doesn't exist: $_"
        }
        $true
    })]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string[]]$Path
)

function Select-Data
{
    [CmdLetBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        $Data
    )

    Begin
    {
        # Setup custom date formatting rules for input data
        # https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx
        $DateFmt = @{
            # The year as a four-digit number
            # The month, from 01 through 12
            Month = 'yyyy/MM'

            # The day of the month, from 01 through 31
            # The month, from 01 through 12
            # The year as a four-digit number,
            First = 'dd-MM-yyyy'

            # The day of the month, from 01 through 31
            # The month, from 01 through 12
            # The year as a four-digit number,
            Second = 'dd-MM-yyyy'

            # The day of the month, from 01 through 31
            # The month, from 01 through 12
            # The year as a four-digit number,
            Third = 'dd-MM-yyyy'
        }

        # Setup custom names
        $Source = @{
            Google = 'Google'
            Yahoo = 'Yahoo'
        }

        # Setup custom statuses
        $Status = @{
            Lost = 'Lost'
            Active = 'Active'
        }

        $Misc = @{
            NA = 'N/A'
            Culture = ([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
        }
    }

    Process
    {
        $Data |
            Select-Object @{Label = 'Month' ; Expression = {if($_.Month -eq $Misc.NA){$_.Month}else{[DateTime]::ParseExact($_.Month, $DateFmt.Month, $Misc.Culture)}}},
                @{Label = 'Name' ; Expression = {$_.Name.Trim("'")}},
                @{Label = 'First' ; Expression = {if($_.First -eq $Misc.NA){$_.First}else{[DateTime]::ParseExact($_.First, $DateFmt.First, $Misc.Culture)}}}, 
                @{Label = 'Second' ; Expression = {if($_.Second -eq $Misc.NA){$_.Second}else{[DateTime]::ParseExact($_.Second, $DateFmt.Second, $Misc.Culture)}}}, 
                @{Label = 'Third' ; Expression = {if($_.Third -eq $Misc.NA){$_.Third}else{[DateTime]::ParseExact($_.Third, $DateFmt.Third, $Misc.Culture)}}}, 
                Status |
            ForEach-Object {
                $i++
                Write-Verbose ('=' * 30 + "[ Processing record #$i ]" + '=' * 30)
                $_
            } |
            Where-Object {
                Write-Verbose "[Selecting only $($Source.Google) records]"
                Write-Verbose "Name: $($_.Name)"
                if($_.Name -eq $Source.Google)
                {
                    Write-Verbose "Found $($Source.Google) record, returning: $true"
                    return $true
                }
                else
                {
                    Write-Verbose "Not found $($Source.Google) record, returning: $false"
                    return $false
                }
            } |
            Where-Object {
                Write-Verbose "[Selecting only those records where Third column date is of current month ($((Get-Date).Month)) in this year ($((Get-Date).Year)) or $($Misc.NA)]"
                Write-Verbose "Third column value is: $($_.Third)"
                if($_.Third -eq $Misc.NA)
                {
                    Write-Verbose "Third column value is equal to: $($Misc.NA), returning: $true"
                    return $true
                }
                else
                {
                    Write-Verbose "Third column value converted to date is: $($_.Third.ToLongDateString())"
                    if($_.Third.Year -eq (Get-Date).Year)
                    {
                        Write-Verbose "Third column date is in current year ($((Get-Date).Year)): $($_.Third.Year)"
                        if($_.Third.Month -eq (Get-Date).Month)
                        {
                            Write-Verbose "Third column date is in current month ($((Get-Date).Month)): $($_.Third.Month), returning: $true"
                            return $true
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Write-Verbose "Third column date is not in current month ($((Get-Date).Month)): $($_.Third.Month), returning: $false"
                            return $false
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         Write-Verbose "Third column date is not in current year ($((Get-Date).Year)): $($_.Third.Year), returning: $false"
                         return $false
                    }
                }
            } |
            Where-Object {
                Write-Verbose '[Selecting records where Month value equals last two months and Status is Active]'
                Write-Verbose "Status column value is: $($_.Status)"
                if($_.Status -eq $Status.Active)
                {
                    Write-Verbose "Status column value is equal to: $($Status.Active)"
                    if($_.Month -ge (Get-Date).AddMonths(-2))
                    {
                        Write-Verbose "Month column date is: $($_.Month.ToLongDateString()), looks like it less than 2 months old, returning $true"
                        return $true
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Write-Verbose "Month column date is: $($_.Month.ToLongDateString()), looks like it more than 2 months old, returning $false"
                        return $false
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Write-Verbose "Status column value is not equal to: $($Status.Active), returning $false"
                    return $false
                }
            } |
            Where-Object {
                Write-Verbose '[Skip records for current month from past year in First and Second columns]'
                Write-Verbose "First column date is: $($_.First.ToLongDateString())"
                Write-Verbose "Second column date is: $($_.Second.ToLongDateString())"

                $ret = $_.First, $_.Second |
                    Where-Object {
                        if($_.Month -eq (Get-Date).Month)
                        {
                            Write-Verbose "Month of date $($_) is equal to current month: $((Get-Date).Month)"
                            if($_.Year -eq (Get-Date).Year)
                            {
                                Write-Verbose "Year of date $($_.ToLongDateString()) is equal to current year: $((Get-Date).Year), returning $true"
                                return $true
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Write-Verbose "Year of date $($_.ToLongDateString()) is not equal to current year: $((Get-Date).Year), returning $false"
                                return $false
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Write-Verbose "Month of date $($_.ToLongDateString()) is not equal to current month: $((Get-Date).Month), returning $true"
                            return $true
                        }
                    }
                if([array]$ret.Count -eq 2)
                {
                    Write-Verbose "Both First and Second columns are not in current month from past years"
                    return $true
                }
                else
                {
                    Write-Verbose "First or Second columns is in current month ($((Get-Date).Year)) from past year, returning $false"
                    return $false
                }
            }
    }
}

# Import data and process data
Write-Verbose 'Importing CSV''s'
$Path |
    Import-Csv |
        Select-Data
Write-Verbose 'All done'
```

Comment: I tried running this code, it doesn't give any error, nor any output. What is the role of $true? Kindly see edit, for more information.

Comment: @msinfo About `$true`: `Where-Object` evaluates scriptblock (expression in curly braces) and passes object further into pipeline if result is `true`, or throws object away if result is `false`. So I just process data inside scriptblock manually and tell `Where-Object` what to do by returning `true` or nothing (equals `false`). Considering date formats: yes, that's a developer's hell. I'll try to come out with solution that'll allow you specify date format. Also, I've tested this script on your data and it works, so could you post real-life example of your CSV, so we all can test our solutions?

Comment: Thanks for explanation about $true. I am still testing on this data only, because actual data has large no. of columns and records, so I have just taken, only those which are actually necessary. But when I run your code, it just prints code (in ISE), and no results are visible. No issue though, from past 2 days, I have been trying to solve this, and it looks I am little close to it. Will try new things now, in combination.

Comment: *But when I run your code, it just prints code (in ISE), and no results are visible.* Do you mean it prints the entire PowerShell code of my example, or just nothing? If it's entire code, maybe it has something to do with PowerShell version (it's older than mine and don't likes formatting?). If it's just nothing, then please check if your dates in CSV is valid, because your current example wouldn't work - it's March already and all the dates in the `Third` and `Month` columns are from February (rule `#2`)

Comment: @msinfo Check the new script!

Comment: Thanks for code, information and explanation. Your approach not only solved this problem, but also my future doubts regarding csv files, and their manipulation. It helps a lot to debug and understand the code logic your way. Did some practice tests with actual data, and its giving desired results. Now I am little more confident with .csv files manipulation using PowerShell. But, its sad that I can accept only one answer.