# The months difference between dates using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, date

I need to have AD User Account Expiration Date and now how many months and date its remain until will be disabled.

I tried the code under but I am getting in the months 1 and I have less than one month I would like to have answer like 0 month and 27 days

```
$StartDate (DateNow)
2019-08-29 00:00:00

AccountExpirationDate                                                                                                                                                                         
---------------------                                                                                                                                                                         
2019-09-26 00:00:00    

$ExpirDate = Get-ADUser test111 -Properties AccountExpirationDate | select AccountExpirationDate

AccountExpirationDate                                                                                                                                                                         
---------------------                                                                                                                                                                         
2019-09-26 00:00:00    

$EndDate= $ExpirDate.AccountExpirationDate

2019-09-26 00:00:00 


$StartDate = (GET-DATE)

2019-08-29 00:00:00


NEW-TIMESPAN –Start $StartDate –End $EndDate

Days              : 27
Hours             : 10
Minutes           : 29
Seconds           : 56


$monthdiff = $EndDate.month - $StartDate.month + (($EndDate.Year - $StartDate.year) * 12)

1
```

(Here I got the number 1 but I have less than one month)

Comment: That is expected, if you take 2018-12-31 and 2019-01-01 and only compare the year you will also get 1 year difference. `$EndDate.Month` returns an integer no longer a datetime type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between dates using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052812/difference-between-dates-using-powershell)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can just do normal arithmetic on dates, but if there are no months, it will return $null not 0.

```
$today - date
$ExpirDate = Get-ADUser test111 -Properties AccountExpirationDate | select AccountExpirationDate

$diffday = $today - $expirDate

$diffday.days
$diffday.months

if ($diffday.months -eq $null)
{
$Diffday.months =0
}
```

Comment: To clarify, math between dates will return a `Timespan` type.

Comment: I didn't get any value in $diffday.months !

Comment: Should there be a value? As in does the period expand longer than a month?

Answer (score 2):

I found no easy way to do this in PowerShell (as [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-timespan) doesn't support month counting), hence I ended up with the following. Starting with the years of the two dates, take their difference and course correct if the start day hasn't passed in the current year. Then do the same with the months:

```
$StartDate = [DateTime]'2021-01-23'
$today = Get-Date
$daydiff = New-TimeSpan -Start $StartDate -End $today
    
$yeardiff = $today.year - $StartDate.year
If($yeardiff -gt 0 -And $StartDate.month -gt $today.month 
  -And $StartDate.day -gt $today.day) { 
    $yeardiff = $yeardiff -1 
}
    
$monthdiff = $today.month - $StartDate.month + ($yeardiff * 12)
If($StartDate.day -gt $today.day) { $monthdiff = $monthdiff -1 }
    
Write-Host "$($daydiff.days) days | $($monthdiff) months"
```

Simplest solution I could work out.

Comment: Doesn't work on $StartDate = (get-date 2021-02-20)
$today = (get-date 2022-01-19

Comment: @bushed I imagine it doesn't, as the $StartDate is after $today. You could always add a comparison of them in the script, and use the more recent one as $today?

Comment: 2021-02-20 is not after 2022-01-19 you can also try $startDate as  2021-02-20 and $today=$StartDate.AddDays(333)

Answer (score 0):

I get the number of months between the start date and the monthly anniversary day in the current month. Then adjust:

```
$start_date = Get-Date '2022-02-27 21:00'
$end_date = Get-Date

# get the monthly anniversary of the $start_date in the current month
$this_month_anniversary = Get-Date ('{0}-{1}-{2} {3:d2}:{4:d2}' -f $end_date.Year, $end_date.Month, $start_date.Day, $start_date.Hour, $start_date.Minute)

# get the number days in the month, so we can get a denominator when figuring the percent of the way we are towards the next anniversay.
# Which month? If we're past this month's anniversary use the current month. If we haven't reached it yet, use the previous month
if  ($end_date -gt $this_month_anniversary) {
    $days_in_month =  [DateTime]::DaysInMonth($end_date.Year, $end_date.Month)
} else {
    $last_month = (Get-Date ('{0}-{1}-01' -f $end_date.Year, $end_date.Month)).AddDays(-1)
    $days_in_month =  [DateTime]::DaysInMonth($last_month.Year, $last_month.Month)
}

# get months between the start date and this month's anniversay, then
# adjust for the current month, this will be negative if the anniversay hasn't occured yet, otherwise positive
($this_month_anniversary.Month - $start_date.month + (($this_month_anniversary.Year - $start_date.year) * 12) +
    (New-TimeSpan -Start $this_month_anniversary -End $end_date).TotalDays / $days_in_month)
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is what you want, or can be tweaked to achieve it relatively easily.

```
$today = Get-Date;
$endOfYearDate = "12/31/$($today.Year)";
$endOfYear = Get-Date($endOfYearDate);
$monthsLeftInTheYear = ($endOfYear.Month - $today.Month);
$daysLeftInTheYear = ($endOfYear - $today);
$daysLefInTheYear.Days;
```

Comment: Doesn't answer question (months difference) and it has a typo in last line so doesn't even work.